# How to find correlation between 2 binary variables using Stata?

Tags: correlation, stata, binary-data

I am trying to find a correlation between two binary variables. How can this be done using Stata? Also, if I use the Probit function, how do I analyze it?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [tetrachoric correlation coefficient](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rtetrachoric.pdf). It is not a correlation between two binary variables, but the Pearson correlation between two *underlying* continuous ones. It also ranges from -1 to 1.

Quoting from the Stata help file for this command:

> Tetrachoric correlations assume a latent bivariate normal distribution
>   $(X_1, X_2)$ for each pair of variables $(v_1, v_2)$, with a threshold model
>   for the manifest variables, $v_i = 1$ if and only if $X_i > 0.$ The means
>   and variances of the latent variables are not identified, but the
>   correlation [...] of $X_1$ and $X_2$ can be estimated from the joint
>   distribution of $v_1$ and $v_2$ and is called the tetrachoric correlation
>   coefficient.

To use this, you have to makes the case that underlying latent bivariate normal variables is meaningful for your data. The other thing to remember is that you must interpret the model in terms of the underlying continuous variables, not the binary ones. So this is not quite what you asked for, but may be a good proxy for something I don't think is really possible.

Here's an example using the survey of attitudes on gender, relationships and family dataset. First, we load the data and calculate the TCCC $\rho$ (or rho) between two binary questions:

```
. webuse familyvalues
(Attitudes on gender, relationships and family)

. tetrachoric RS074 RS075

   Number of obs =        3,300
 Tetrachoric rho =       0.0679
       Std error =       0.0302

Test of Ho: RS074 and RS075 are independent
 2-sided exact P =       0.0278
```

The tetrachoric correlation between thinking that contact with in-laws is important and that women in charge is bad is weak and positive, but significantly different from zero, at 0.0679 on the [-1,1] scale. Again, this is the correlation for the variables on the latent scale, where respondents can agree strongly, weakly, or disagree entirely, or fall anywhere in between. This is not a correlation between binary yes-no survey responses, except in so far as there is a mapping between the unseen continuous attitude data and the observed survey responses.

You could use a `probit` model (which also makes its own distributional assumptions), but that route will not yield a correlation. Here's an example:

```
. probit RS074 i.RS075

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -2287.3857  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -2284.8729  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -2284.8729  

Probit regression                               Number of obs     =      3,300
                                                LR chi2(1)        =       5.03
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0250
Log likelihood = -2284.8729                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0011

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       RS074 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     1.RS075 |   .1166852   .0520734     2.24   0.025     .0146232    .2187472
       _cons |  -.0265647   .0248322    -1.07   0.285     -.075235    .0221056
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins, over(RS075)

Predictive margins                              Number of obs     =      3,300
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(RS074), predict()
over         : RS075

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       RS075 |
          0  |   .4894035   .0099031    49.42   0.000     .4699937    .5088132
          1  |   .5359043   .0181861    29.47   0.000     .5002602    .5715483
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins, dydx(RS075)

Conditional marginal effects                    Number of obs     =      3,300
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(RS074), predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : 1.RS075

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     1.RS075 |   .0465008   .0207076     2.25   0.025     .0059147    .0870869
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
```

After fitting the `probit` and getting the coefficients, the first `margins` calculates the predicted probability that in-law contact is important for those who disagree that women in charge bad (~49%) and those who agree with that statement (~54%). The second `margins` gives you the difference between the two predictions, which is just under 5 percentage points. This means that respondents who answer that having women in charge is bad are somewhat more likely to report that you need to have dinner with the in-laws. This difference is significant.

To sum up, both the probit and tetrachoric correlation give you similar answers about the relationship between these question and their statistical significance.

You can also explore the `tabulate twoway` command if you want some other ways to look at this sort of data.